# Remove substring if number exists before keyword

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a strings with the form:

```
5 dogs = 1 medium size house
4 cats = 2 small houses
one bird = 1 bird cage
```

What I amt trying to do is remove the substring that exists before the equals sign but only if the substring contains a keyword and the data before that keyword is a integer.

So in this example my key words are:

```
dogs,
cats,
bird
```

In the above example, the ideal output of my process would be:

1 medium size house

2 small houses

one bird = 1 bird cage

My code so far looks like this (I am hard coding the keyword values/strings for now)

```
var orginalstring= "5 dogs = 1 medium size house";
int equalsindex = originalstring.indexof('=');
var prefix = originalstring.Substring(0,equalsindex);
if(prefix.Contains("dogs")
     {
       var modifiedstring = originalstring.Remove(prefix).Replace("=", string.empty);
       return modifiedstring;
      }
return originalstring;
```

The issue here is that I am removing the whole substring regardless of whether or not the data preceding the keyword is a number.

Would somebody be able to help me with this additional logic?

Thanks so much as always for anybody who takes a few minutes to read this question.

Mick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a simple regex of the form

```
\d+\s+(?:kw1|kw2|kw3|...)\s*=\s*
```

where `kwX` is the corresponding keyword.

```
var data = new[] {
    "5 dogs = 1 medium size house",
    "4 cats = 2 small houses",
    "one bird = 1 bird cage"
};
var keywords = new[] {"dogs", "cats", "bird"};
var regexStr = string.Format( @"\d+\s+(?:{0})\s*=\s*", string.Join("|", keywords));
var regex = new Regex(regexStr);
foreach (var s in data) {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", regex.Replace(s, string.Empty));
}
```

In the example above the call of `string.Format` pastes the list of keywords joined by `|` into the "template" of the expression at the top of the post, i.e.

```
\d+\s+(?:dogs|cats|bird)\s*=\s*
```

This expression matches

- One or more digits `\d+`, followed by
- One or more space `\s+`, followed by
- A keyword from the list: dogs, cats, bird `(?:dogs|cats|bird)`, followed by
- Zero or more spaces `\s*`, followed by
- An equal sign `=`, followed by
- Zero or more spaces `\s*`

The rest is easy: since this regex matches the part that you wish to remove, you need to call `Replace` and pass it `string.Empty`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/OH1Vph)

Comment: Obviously Regex is new territory for the poster.  Could you elaborate on why your Regex works?

Comment: Blinken, I really appreciated the detailed answer and demo.  I will try to combine it with what Mike gave me below to see if I understand and report back with how it works out.

Comment: I would love an explanation of the regex if you have the time for sure

Comment: MikeH and dasblinkenlight....I have had a regex epiphany thanks to your collective input.  Things are working as I had hoped now. I'm taking some good knowledge away.  I am going to give the check to dasblinkenlight because I derived my solution from that code, but many thanks to you too MikeH.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex (`System.Text.RegularExpressions`) to identify whether or not there is a number in the string.

```
Regex r = new Regex("[0-9]"); //Look for a number between 0 and 9
bool hasNumber = r.IsMatch(prefix);
```

This Regex simply searches for any number in the string.  If you want to search for a number-space-string you could use `[0-9] [a-z]|[A-Z]`.  The `|` is an "or" so that both upper and lower case letters result in a match.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks so much for the quick reply. Regex is a bit overwhelming for me so please forgive if this is a naive question.  Does this regex look for only numbers before the key word or any number? So in this case "5 dogs" & "dogs 5" would be treated equally?

Comment: I'll agree Regex is a bit of a beast.  In my example both would be treated equally.  You could change the Regex to `"[0-9] [a-z]"` to match "5 dogs" but not "dogs 5" (also "5 DOGS" would fail).  You should take a look at Regex a bit more in depth, it's useful in tons of situations.

Comment: @IrishMickeyWard I've added a bit more to the answer that may be helpful.

Comment: Mike, thanks so much for the help this will definitely help to get me where I need to go!  I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
int i;
if(int.TryParse(prefix.Substring(0, 1), out i)) //try to get an int from first char of prefix
{
//remove prefix
}
```

This will only work for single-digit integers, however.